# Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on Sony Vaio SVS1513C5E

Tags: system-installation, fan, vaio, fancontrol

I decided to clean up my 3y old Windows HDD and install Ubuntu again but I'm out of practice and have forgotten most of things I did last time I installed.

I do remember having issues with cooling fan being loud last time I had Ubuntu installed.

Any idea how to fix it? Is there anything I should take care about while installing?

Thank you much for your guidance! Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the fan being loud. Maybe TLP will fix that: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html

Other than that, Just go with 14.04.3 if its an old laptop. Should be more stable.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks Joakim, I successfully installed 14.04 LTS and the fan is loud. TLP is running but its not helping. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you certain its not an hardware "issue"? If its out of warranty maybe open it up and clean it? Possible put new thermal paste on it.

Comment: It purrs like a kitten on Windows 7 :) A mix of 'TLP' and 'powertop' seems to work, CPU usage can be higher then expected but it is definitely better with TLP and powertop! Thanks for the first tip, it leaded me to powertop.